# What does C++ struct syntax "a : b" mean

Tags: c++, data-structures, syntax, struct

If I have a C++ struct, defining a 64bit data word such as..

```
struct SMyDataWord
{
    int Name : 40;
    int Colour : 24;
};
```

What does the `: 40` syntax mean... does it mean that the first 40 bits are reserved for the Name and the remaining 24 bits for the Colour?

This is how it appears to be being used, but I've not come across it before.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Bitfields, carried over from C. `Name` is 40 bits wide, `Colour` is 24 bits wide. Your struct therefore has at least 64 bits. On my system 64 bits would be 8 bytes.

Comment: On what system would 64bits not be 8 bytes?

Comment: To be pedantic, the number of bits in a byte is implementation dependent (see either of the C, C++ standard). This is given by the CHAR_BIT macro in the 'limits' header.

Comment: Some IBM mainframes have had 9bit bytes, IIRC.

Comment: ... and on such systems (where a byte is a multiple of 3) do octals wield their superiority when doing bit fiddling (yes, I know, I digress).

Comment: *at least 64*? not precisely? Do you mean that struct may occupy bits more than 64?

Comment: @zhangxaochen: I may be wrong, but I think compilers are able to pad/align structs as they deem best. If the bytesize is different, this might cause different compilers to align differently on the same or on different systems.

Answer (score 16):

Here `sizeof` nicely demonstrates what's going on under the hood:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

struct bc_1 {
   int a : 1;
   int b : 1;
};

struct bc_2 {
   int a : 31;
   int b : 1;
};

struct bc_3 {
   int a : 32;
   int b : 1;
};

struct bc_4 {
   int a : 31;
   int b : 2;
};

struct bc_5 {
   int a : 32;
   int b : 32;
};

struct bc_6 {
   int a : 40;
   int b : 32;
};

struct bc_7 {
   int a : 63;
   int b : 1;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << "CHAR_BIT = " << CHAR_BIT;
    std::cout << " => sizeof(int) = " << sizeof(int) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "1,  1:  " << sizeof(struct bc_1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "31, 1:  " << sizeof(struct bc_2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "32, 1:  " << sizeof(struct bc_3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "31, 2:  " << sizeof(struct bc_4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "32, 32: " << sizeof(struct bc_5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "40, 32: " << sizeof(struct bc_6) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "63, 1:  " << sizeof(struct bc_7) << std::endl;
}
```

What follows depends on your compiler and OS, and possibly on your hardware. On macOS with gcc-7 (with a `CHAR_BIT` = 8, a 32 bit `int` (i.e. half of 64 bit `long`) has `sizeof(int)` = 4) this is the output I see:

```
CHAR_BIT = 8 => sizeof(int) = 4
1,  1:  4
31, 1:  4
32, 1:  8
31, 2:  8
32, 32: 8
40, 32: 12
63, 1:  8
```

This tells us several things: if both fields of `int` type fit into a single `int` (i.e. 32 bits in the example above), the compiler allocates only a single `int`'s worth of memory (`bc_1` and `bc_2`). Once, a single `int` can't hold the bitfields anymore, we add a second one (`bc_3` and `bc_4`). Note that `bc_5` is at capacity.

Interestingly, we can "select" more bits than allowed. See `bc_6`. Here g++-7 gives a warning:

```
bitfields.cpp::30:13: warning: width of 'bc_6::a' exceeds its type
     int a : 40;
             ^~
```

Note that: clang++ explains this in better detail

```
bitfields.cpp:30:9: warning: width of bit-field 'a' (40 bits) exceeds the width of its type; value will be truncated to 32 bits [-Wbitfield-width]
    int a : 40;
    ^
```

However it seems that under the hood, the compiler allocates another `int`'s worth of memory. Or at the very least, it determines the correct size. I guess the compiler is warning us not to access this memory as `int a = bc_6::a` (I would wager that `int a` would then only have the first 32 bits of field `bc_6::a`...). This is confirmed by `bc_7` whose total size is that of two `int`s, but the first field covers most of them.

Finally replacing `int` with `long` in the example above behaves as expected:

```
CHAR_BIT = 8 => sizeof(long) = 8
1,  1:  8
31, 1:  8
32, 1:  8
31, 2:  8
32, 32: 8
40, 32: 16
63, 1:  8
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, that is the syntax for [bitfields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-bit-fields?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160). They are commonly used to define structs that map onto hardware registers. There are some things to keep in mind if you decide to use them, one is that you can't know how the compiler does the layout, ordering and padding in the actual bytes making up the fields can and will differ among compilers (and perhaps with the same compiler but with different optimization settings, too).

Comment: In the MSDN link you offered, there is a line: *Note that nYear is 8 bits long and would overflow the word boundary of the declared type, unsigned int. Therefore, it is begun at the beginning of a new unsigned int.* Is it wrong explanation according to the figure above it?

Answer (score 7):

That's a bitfield definition.

Name is an integer that's able to store exactly 40 bits of information. Colour can store 24 bits.

This is often done to save some space in often needed structures, or compress code down to a size that's easy to handle for the CPU (in your case 64 bits. Fit's exactly into a CPU register on a 64 bit machine).

The code that accesses the bitfields will execute a tad slower though.

Answer (score 3):

[Use them judiciously](https://web.archive.org/web/20160412094446/http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=131):

> Remember that almost everything about
> bit fields is implementation
> dependent. For example, whether bits
> are stored left-to-right or
> right-to-left depends on the actual
> hardware architecture. Furthermore,
> each compiler uses a different member
> alignment model, which is why the size
> of the optimized BillingRec is 12
> bytes rather than 9. You cannot take a
> bit field's address nor can you create
> an arrays of bits. Finally, on most
> implementations the use of bit fields
> incurs speed overhead. Therefore, when
> you optimize your code, measure the
> effect of a certain optimization and
> its tradeoffs before you decide to use
> it.