# ":" (colon) in C struct - what does it mean?

Tags: c++, c

```
struct _USBCHECK_FLAGS
    {
        unsigned char   DEVICE_DEFAULT_STATE       : 1;
        unsigned char   DEVICE_ADDRESS_STATE       : 1;
        unsigned char   DEVICE_CONFIGURATION_STATE : 1;
        unsigned char   DEVICE_INTERFACE_STATE     : 1;
        unsigned char   FOUR_RESERVED_BITS         : 8;
        unsigned char   RESET_BITS                 : 8;
    } State_bits;
```

What does `:1` and `:8` mean?

Comment: [Bitfields in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Bit_fields).

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field for examples

Comment: "FOUR_RESERVED_BITS        : 8" ...

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Those are bit fields. Basically, the number after the colon describes how many bits that field uses. Here is a [quote from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yszfawxh.aspx) describing bit fields:

> The constant-expression specifies the width of the field in bits. The
>   type-specifier for the declarator must be unsigned int, signed int, or
>   int, and the constant-expression must be a nonnegative integer value.
>   If the value is zero, the declaration has no declarator. Arrays of bit
>   fields, pointers to bit fields, and functions returning bit fields are
>   not allowed. The optional declarator names the bit field. Bit fields
>   can only be declared as part of a structure. The address-of operator
>   (&) cannot be applied to bit-field components.
>
> Unnamed bit fields cannot be referenced, and their contents at run
>   time are unpredictable. They can be used as "dummy" fields, for
>   alignment purposes. An unnamed bit field whose width is specified as 0
>   guarantees that storage for the member following it in the
>   struct-declaration-list begins on an int boundary.
>
> This example defines a two-dimensional array of structures named screen.

```
struct 
{
    unsigned short icon : 8;
    unsigned short color : 4;
    unsigned short underline : 1;
    unsigned short blink : 1;
} screen[25][80];
```

Edit: another important bit from the MSDN link:

> Bit fields have the same semantics as the integer type. This means a
>   bit field is used in expressions in exactly the same way as a variable
>   of the same base type would be used, regardless of how many bits are
>   in the bit field.

A quick sample illustrates this nicely. Interestingly, with mixed types the compiler seems to default to `sizeof (int)`.

```
  struct
  {
    int a : 4;
    int b : 13;
    int c : 1;
  } test1;

  struct
  {
    short a : 4;
    short b : 3;
  } test2;

  struct
  {
    char a : 4;
    char b : 3;
  } test3;

  struct
  {
    char a : 4;
    short b : 3;
  } test4;

  printf("test1: %d\ntest2: %d\ntest3: %d\ntest4: %d\n", sizeof(test1), sizeof(test2), sizeof(test3), sizeof(test4));
```

> test1: 4
>
> test2: 2
>
> test3: 1
>
> test4: 4

Comment: I still don't get it. Does that mean C++ automatically merges your "variables" into size of an int, so that all bits are used? Can you cast bit field structiores to numbers to obtain the typical "*int with flags*".

Comment: @TomášZato I have updated my answer with more information for you

Comment: @JoeFish Can you elaborate the merging details of the `test1-4`?

Comment: I don't understand why `test4: 4` and I got `test4: 2` on Darwin Kernel Version 17.0.0 x86_64

Comment: @Aleksey Remember that almost everything about bit fields is implementation dependent. it depends on hardware architecture and structure member alignment model.

Comment: @smwikipedia  provoid a simple and understandable principles here: if both fields of `int` type can fit into a single int  (i.e. 32 bits in the example above), the compiler allocates only a single int's worth of memory (test_1,  short type for test_2, char type for test3). Ignored in the above example, if a single int can't hold the bitfields anymore, we add a second one. ref to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49722670/8691463) for more elaborate explanation.

Answer (score 25):

I also ran into the colon notation but in my context bit fields didn't make sense. So I did some digging. This notation is also used for assigning values - in my specific situation pointers to functions.

Source: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/c577.htm

Below is a sample and an excerpt to explain.

"**There is a gcc extension that makes assigning to this structure more convenient**. You'll see it in modern drivers, and may catch you by surprise. This is what the new way of assigning to the structure looks like:"

```
struct file_operations fops = {
   read: device_read,
   write: device_write,
   open: device_open,
   release: device_release
};
```

The C99 (old, compatible) way looks like:

```
struct file_operations fops = {
   .read = device_read,
   .write = device_write,
   .open = device_open,
   .release = device_release
};
```

Comment: I have also seen this! I always thought the gcc extension was `.x = y` and the standard adopted it, until later I saw the `x: y` notation. The standard one looks better, I believe.

Comment: Firstly, this is not assignment, it is *initialization*. Secondly, the feature you describe (*designated initializers*) has absolutely nothing to do with what the question is about (*bit fields*). Just because the obsolete GCC extension used `:` in the syntax does not mean it is in any way related to `:` in the question.

Comment: AnT, someone searching for "C struct initialization colon" may find this answer, and it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, user27346!

Comment: Later readers need to be aware of ：colon `：` appear in c structure declaration(the question belongs to) and initialization at definition(the answer belongs to) are not the same thing.