# How this C struct outputs the value?

Tags: c, struct

I am beginner in C and can't understood how this piece of code is working:

```
struct marks{
  int p:3;
  int c:3;
  int m:2;
};

void main(){
  struct marks s={2,-6,5};
  printf("%d %d %d", s.p, s.c, s.m); 
}
```

I found that the output is: `2 2 1`

But after a lot of try I was unable to figure out how the output is like that. I have less knowledge about the struct. That's why may be I am feeling some problem here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use bit-fields in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933242/when-to-use-bit-fields-in-c)

Comment: The int `c` and `p` have only 3 bits. With 3 bits you have only 8 possible values: from 0 to 7 using `unsigned int`, from 0 to 3 and from -1 to -4 using (signed) `int`. You cannot insert the value -6 into a 3 bit `int`, if you assign it only the 3 less significant bits are set into the variable.

Comment: What did you expect? Why do you think you can put two buckets full of water into a single bucket? That's not even related to bit-fields, but simply using too small integer types. Did you enable compiler wanrnings? Why not? If yes: didn't the complier warn? Why did you ignore them? Your code relies on implementation defined conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, inside the `struct` you defined- `p:3`, `c:2`, `m:2` are actually denoting the bit fields. To know more about bit fields in C go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564532/colon-in-c-struct-what-does-it-mean) in SO or this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) in Wikipedia.

For simplicity, know that the 3 or 2 after the colon(:) sign is representing bit-fields of width 3 or 2. That means 3 or 2 adjacent computer memory locations which have been allocated to hold a sequence of bits.

Now, inside the `main()` function of your code:

```
struct marks s={2,-6,5};
```

Here,

> Binary value of 2: 00000010
>
> Binary value of -6: 11111010
>
> Binary value of 5: 00000101

Now according to bit-fields, from binary value of 2, we will take last 3 digits which is 010 (in decimal it is 2) and from binary value of -6, we will take last 2 digits which is 10 (in decimal it is 2) and from binary value of 5, we will take last 3 digits which is 01 (in decimal it is 1) and finally assign them to p, c or m.

That's how the output comes as `2 2 1`.

Hope, I could make you clear.

Comment: C does not support _methods_. An `main` is not a _method_ in C++ either. And your explanation is not quite correct. The result is implementation defined, there is no guarantee for this result.

Comment: Thanks.that was my mistake(it would be main() function).edited.

Comment: But how the result is not guaranteed. Can you make it more clear? It will be helpful for everyone. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

first of all your declaration of struct is using bit fields.

```
struct marks{
int p:3;
int c:3;
int m:2;
};
```

here p:3 means we are defining P to be an int and we are preserving only 3 bit of the given number. For example , You need 3 bits to represent the value 5, which would be represented as 101. The lower 2 bits are the value 1. That's why you get m=1.

[This link will give you more explanation.](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/79891/)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful :)