# kernel programming & strange struct

Tags: c, linux, struct, kernel

in `linux/fs.h` I found strange struct `file_operations`:

```
struct file_operations fops = {
    read: device_read,
    write: device_write,
    open: device_open,
    release: device_release
};
```

and my questions is what is the name of this type of giving value?

Comment: Please assume that I am using a screenreader and trying to answer your question. Can you see the problem?

Comment: please don't use images, write code.
By the way, where do you find it ? Because https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/fs.h#L3397

Comment: this is an initialization, the struct fields are pointer to function, the form is their initialization

Comment: and those _strange_ things are called function pointers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [":" (colon) in C struct - what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564532/colon-in-c-struct-what-does-it-mean). One of its [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19691081/3440745) describes **exactly** your example.

Answer (score 1):

From
https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html

2.4.2.3 Initializing Structure Members

> Another way to initialize the members is to specify the name of the
> member to initialize. This way, you can initialize the members in any
> order you like, and even leave some of them uninitialized. There are
> two methods that you can use. The first method is available in C99 and
> as a C89 extension in GCC:
>
> `struct point first_point = { .y = 10, .x = 5 };`
>
> You can also omit the
> period and use a colon instead of ‘=’, though this is a GNU C
> extension:
>
> `struct point first_point = { y: 10, x: 5 };`

So this is equivalent to

```
struct file_operations fops = {
    .read = device_read,
    .write = device_write,
    .open = device_open,
    .release = device_release
};
```

Comment: that will not help the OP if you do not say what it is ... ;-)

Comment: I have added link to https://www.gnu.org/ explaining this