# Ip Struct C parameters

Tags: c, sockets, struct

I have started one adventure in raw sockets and I found one ip header that I don't understand, my doubt is

- hdrlen:4

> This two points four are used for what?

- **attribute**((**packed**));

> What is this attribute?

```
struct iphdr {
    uint8_t   hdrlen:4;
    uint8_t   version:4;
    uint8_t   ecn:2;       // Explicit Congestion Notification - RFC 3168
    uint8_t   dscp:6;      // DiffServ Code Point
    uint16_t  length;
    uint16_t  ident;
    uint16_t  fragoff:13;
    uint16_t  flags:3;
    uint8_t   ttl;
    uint8_t   protocol;
    uint16_t  checksum;
    uint32_t  srcip;
    uint32_t  dstip;
    uint32_t  options[ ];  // Present if hdrlen > 5
} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does C++ struct syntax "a : b" mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824295/what-does-c-struct-syntax-a-b-mean)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604968/what-does-a-colon-in-a-struct-declaration-mean-such-as-1-7-16-or-32/1604972#1604972

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568432/is-gccs-attribute-packed-pragma-pack-unsafe

Comment: I don't think the question is just "what do these mean", but also "why are these used here"—knowing that this struct is using bit fields isn't that useful if you don't know _why_ it uses bit fields. ("used for what" ==> _what_ and _why_)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This struct represents a data packet that is going to be sent over the network, so you don't want to waste a single bit of space (since every bit needs to be sent over the "wire").

The `field_name:field_width` syntax declares a [bit field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yszfawxh.aspx), so `uint8_t   hdrlen:4;` means that you actually only want 4 bits to store the "header length" value (but the compiler will make sure the value is copied into a `uint8_t` (one byte) when you read the field value).

The `__attribute__((__packed__))` syntax tells the compiler to ignore the [usual alignment requirements for structs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86). The compiler is sometimes required to insert padding between struct fields in order to ensure efficient memory access to the fields in the struct. For example, if you have a `uint64_t` right after a `uint8_t`, the compiler would insert padding (garbage) between the two fields to ensure that the `uint64_t` starts on an 8-byte boundary (i.e., the last 3 bits of the pointer address are all zero).

As you can see, all of this bit-twiddling and packing is done so that there is no wasted space in this struct, and every bit that is sent over the network is meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

There is some [padding in structs that is required for alignment requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment), `packed` attribute removes the padding.

Answer (score 0):

> *This two points four are used for what?*

This *"two points four"* is the way to specify [bit-fielded variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field). It basically asks to use that many bits (here, `4`) to represent the value of the variable.

More on this : [Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1604968/2173917)

> *What is this attribute?*

This is a [special property](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html), using which it is indicated that there should be no padding among the structure member variables. In general, `__attribute__` is used to help the compiler to optimize certain properties of functions and/or variables.

More on this:

1. [GNU docs on Variable-attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes)
2. [Structure padding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6968468/2173917)