# Struct memory alignment - How is this called?

Tags: c++, struct, memory-alignment

I have some code where i read chunks of 32 bit in this way

```
struct data{
    unsigned int value : 12;
    unsigned int foo   : 1;
    unsigned int bar   : 2;
    /*...*/          //  ^^ adds up to 32 bits
}

int* rawdata;
for (;;) {
    data* d = (*data)rawdata;
    unsigned int value = d->value;
    rawdata++;
}
```

I know more or less how it works. The `: 12` tells the compiler to read 12 bits (and then interpret them as an `unsigned int`). However, when I was looking for this on the web, I didnt find anything, because I dont know what to search for ("struct memory alignment" didnt yield any useful results). Hence my question:

How is this technique called? Where can I find detailed information on this feature?

Comment: ["bitfield"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824295/what-does-c-struct-syntax-a-b-mean)

Comment: @m.s. I knew it was something easy ;). For some reason I cannot flag my own question as duplicate, maybe I should delete it...

Comment: Also beware that bitfields are not so portable, usually you end up using bitwise logical operators and masking instead.